# oracle sql - join with having with and group by?

Tags: sql, oracle

If I have to find all uses that viewed the same video more than once, then I'm using the following query.

```
SELECT userid AS users,video_id 
FROM watching_list GROUP BY userid , video_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

^^It does give you that, right? If watching_list contains userid and videoid that the user watched and datetime stamp.

What I would like to do is join it to user table, based on userid, to look up user's name etc too and not just the userid.

I tried doing simple join, and of course it broke over me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Users.Name, Users.userid AS users,video_id 
FROM watching_list 
    JOIN Users
        ON Users.UserID = watching_list.UserID
GROUP BY Users.userid , video_id, Users.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Why would this break? It should be the same user, so adding additional info of the same person to the `group by` should not cause a change

[Here is a crude, quick SQLFiddle to prove this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0beea/1)

Answer (score 3):

A somewhat inelegant way to do it is like so:

```
Select USERS.LAST_NAME,
       USERS.FIRST_NAME,
       double_watchers.VIDEO_ID
  FROM USERS,
      (SELECT userid AS users,
              video_id 
         FROM watching_list
        GROUP BY userid , video_id
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) double_watchers
Where double_watchers.userid = users.id;
```

I'm creating an inline table (not sure about terminology) with your original query and then joining it to the USERS table.  There's probably a much more efficient way to do it, but I don't have a test instance in front of me to experiment right now.

Comment: You dont need the subquery at all, a simple join and adding to the group by will work. as long as userid remains in the group by, then adding additional info to the group by based on the user will not do anything

Comment: I would look at the execution plans on real data sets.

I can imagine this being more efficient than the join method because if only a few users meet the "more than once" condition then the inline view will be executed first then a nested loop join used to access the users table. In the join method a hash join between watching_list and users would probably be executed, then an aggregation performed. In fact the aggregation would be more costly in the join-first query because more bytes are in the group by clause.

For these reasons I favour Marc's solution over Justin's.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I agree that this COULD be better, but would suggest that the OP profile both methods to make sure.